# How to have a text input with padding fill its container

Tags: css

Of course, `width: 100%` on a block element fills the container, but only if border, padding, and margin are zero. Putting such an `input` in a containing `div` with padding does the trick, but I'm curious why simply `input {display: block; width: auto;}` doesn't work. Suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with centr0 as to why `width: auto` doesn't work.

If you actually want to get an `input` to be full width of its container, then the following works. Given:

```
<div id="Container">
    <form>
        <input type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Do this with the css:

```
form {
    padding: 0 0 0 14px; 
    }

input {
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -14px;
}
```

**Explanation:** Obviously, the -14px margin on the `input` counteracts the padding added to the `form` element. What is not so obvious is where the `14px` came from. It is equal to the left/right 5px padding of the `input` plus the default for `input` element's border width (2px on all the browsers I tested). So 2 + 5 + 5 + 2 = 14.

To really be sure you are consistent cross-browser, you would want to explicitly set the border width to what you desired for the `input`. If you want a different padding (or thicker/thinner borders), then just redo the math. A 3px padding would be 10px instead of 14px, a 7px padding would be 18px instead of 14px.

For the example, you can set the width of `#Container` (could also be the `body` itself that is just defaulting to 100% of the page width) to what you desire, and the above css should match its width.

Comment: I think `form > div.container > input` is semantically better for most situations. Nevertheless, this solution seems to be the best one on the table.

Answer (score 1):

if i remember correctly the default size of input doesn't span the width of its container.  "width: auto;" is like "resetting" the style back to its default value.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a [Reset CSS Stylesheet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/) then the input element will have some default styling set by the browser, this probably includes padding and margins.

also, `width:auto` will give the browser default.  Try `width:100%`

Comment: The issue that prompts the question is that `width:100%` doesn't allow for borders or padding, since they bring it over 100%.

Comment: I'm confused what the question actually is then? Seems to answer itself.  Padding, Margin and border bring it over  100% because thats how the [css box model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html) works.  total width = width + border + margin + padding.  `width:auto` doesn't work because `width:auto` means something different.

Answer (score -1):

Reset the container's padding resolves the problem.

```
td {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
```